# How to automatically authenticate when launching a web app from Katalon Studio in Firefox

Tags: selenium, authentication, firefox, katalon-studio

[image]

I am making test cases using Katalon Studio. The problem is that when I launch the test case on Firefox it shows me the "Authentication Required" popup. Instead when I use Chrome or Explorer it doesn't happen. How can I get rid of this popup when I use Firefox?

Comment: is it HTTP Basic Authentication dialog? or something else? can you put a screenshot.

Comment: the screenshot has been added to the question

Comment: it says: "http.//localhost:xxxxx requires a username and a password"

Comment: visit website like this `driver.get("http://username:password@WebsiteURL")`

Comment: Already tried.The problem is that I use Katalon Studio. So for me it's WebUI.openBrowser("http://username:password@WebsiteURL"). But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

It should be: WebUI.openBrowser("http://username:password@WebsiteURL") instead of WebUI.openBrowser("username:password@WebsiteURL")

Comment: Have you tried it directly on your browser without using Katalon Studio? Is it the same?

Comment: Yes. If I don't use Katalon Studio the authentication required popup doesn't appear.

Comment: If this method failed, one possiblity is that your password contain special character. In that case you can use `import java.net.URLEncoder;` and then `def password = "myp@ssword"` `password = URLEncoder.encode(password , StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())`

Answer (score -1):

Please try 
`WebUI.Authenticate(url, username ,passsword, timeoutseconds)`.

That should do the job, did it for me .

Comment: It doesn't work. Because I have integrated authentication.

Comment: Hi there , Are you referring to the Login dialog Box right...  what does intergrated mean anyway apart from a jargon...